# Не работает шейдер

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Написал шейдер который должен делать эффект тумана в дали, но он не работает. В чём может быть причина?

Создаю Material выбираю Custom/FogEffect шейдер, устанавливаю цвет тумана после этого, перехожу на камеру вешаю скрипт устанавливаю ссылку на этот Material, и ноль эффекта, как-будто и шейдера нет.

C#

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode, ImageEffectAllowedInSceneView]
public class FogEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material Fog; // Material с туманом

    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Camera>().depthTextureMode = DepthTextureMode.Depth;
    }

    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(src, dest, Fog);
    }
}
```

ShaderLabs

```
Shader "Custom/FogEffect"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _FogColor("Fog Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }
        SubShader
    {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture;
            fixed4 _FogColor;

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float scrPos : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.scrPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                float depthValue = Linear01Depth(tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.scrPos)).r);
                fixed4 fogColor = _FogColor * depthValue;
                return fogColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```